# How to convert string with numeric range into a list in Python

Tags: python, string, list, range

I want to have yourfeedback.
I need to process an input which is a range defined as string:

```
targets = 'machine[7:10]'
```

The result that I need is:

```
results = ['machine07', 'machine08', 'machine09', 'machine10']
```

Here is what I have coded in Python:

```
for target in targets:

    m = re.search('\\d+:\d+\]', target)
    if m:
        name = target.split('[')[0]
        target_range = re.findall('[0-9]+', target)
        print(target_range)
        target_range = [int(i) for i in target_range]
        for tgt in range(target_range[0],target_range[1]+1):
             results.append(name + str(format(tgt, '02d')))
```

Please, can you tell me is there is a more **elegant** way or **pythonic** way 
of doing the same thing ? ... with **NO** import module! Thank you.

Comment: "with no import module" - isn't `re` an imported module?

Comment: I'm guessing they mean "nothing which needs an extra library to be installed"

Comment: Yep my bad **import re** is allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already used `split()` in your code, why not just take that a step farther and eliminate the need for `re`?

```
(base, indices) = targets.split('[')
(start, end) = indices[:-1].split(':')

target_range = []
for i in range(int(start), int(end)+1):
    target_range.append('{0}{1:02}'.format(base, i))
```

Answer (score 3):

Capture the desired substrings in 3 groups. Generate a range object by the last 2 groups by converting them to int.

Then run a for loop on the range object and append to the first group.

You can try something like this:

```
import re

targets = 'machine[7:10]'
a,b,c = re.findall(r'(.*?)\[(\d+):(\d+)\]', targets)[0]
res = [a+'{:0>2}'.format(d) for d in range(int(b),int(c)+1)]
print res
```

Output:

```
['machine07', 'machine08', 'machine09', 'machine10']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [groups](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group):

```
> targets = 'machine[7:10]'
> m = re.match(r'(\w+)\[(\d+):(\d+)\]', targets)
> results = ['{}{:0>2}'.format(m.group(1), str(i)) for i in range(int(m.group(2)), int(m.group(3))+1)]
> results
['machine07', 'machine08', 'machine09', 'machine10']
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension combined with some string splicing is one way to do it without importing anything:

```
targets = 'machine[7:10]'

start_idx = targets.index('[')
separator_idx = targets.index(':')
end_idx = targets.index(']')

name = targets[:start_idx]
range_start = int(targets[start_idx + 1:separator_idx])
range_end = int(targets[separator_idx + 1:end_idx]) + 1

results = [name + "{:02}".format(i) for i in range(range_start, range_end)]

print(results)
```

Comment: Hang on a moment I accidentally hit submit. I'm in the midst of editing my answer.

Comment: OK fine but you are using hardcoded value ... such as `machine` and `7,11` ! I should have specified that from the string itself you need to extract the information. What if my string is : `server[1:25]` !

Comment: @Ep1cF4iL Refresh to see my solution please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
word,nums_ = targets.split('[')
nums = map(int,nums_.replace(']','').split(':'))
nums[-1] = nums[-1]+1
print [word+'{:0>2}'.format(i) for i in range(*nums)]
```

result

```
['machine07', 'machine08', 'machine09', 'machine10']
```

Answer (score 0):

First split into range and target:

```
target, ranges = targets[:-1].split('[')
```

Then get low and high range:

```
range_min, range_max = [int(i) for i in ranges.split(':')]
```

Then loop over range and create string:

```
results = ['{}_{:0>2}'.format(target, i) for i in range(range_min, range_max + 1)]
```

results:

```
['machine_07', 'machine_08', 'machine_09', 'machine_10']
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer something more readable, try to use the new way of formatting strings, it makes everything much clear.

```
targets = 'machine[7:10]'
results = []

name, range_ = targets.split('[')
idx = [int(x) for x in range_[:-1].split(':')]

for i in range(idx[0],idx[1]+1):
    if i < 10:
        results.append(f'{name}0{i}')
    else:
        results.append(f'{name}{i}')

>>>results
>>>['machine07', 'machine08', 'machine09', 'machine10']
```